# What is the best way to delete related records in PostgreSQL, not connected by a direct foreign key?

Tags: postgresql

In order to cut down on "stupid" tables (the ones which are identical for several related parent entities) we made a few generic tables.

Here is an example:

### tbl_settings

- id
- owner_type (e.g. "account", "user" etc.)
- owner_id (actual ID of a foreign table record)
- setting_name
- setting_value

Now the problem are the deletes, where it is quite easy to forget to delete e.g. the user's settings when the user is deleted.

What is the right way to handle deletes for this kind of a table in PostgreSQL?

1. Do it in an application (e.g. when deleting an user, do a manual delete of related settings)?
2. Do it in a database trigger on the tbl_user (and in all other parent tables)?
3. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a tables relationships have meaning only in the application and upwards - i.e. it has no bearing on the referential integrity of the data in the database - you can do this in the application layer.

If "orphaned" records violate *data* (as opposed to business logic) relationships, then do this in the database: the safest way is probably via a trigger, though that has its disadvantages too (e.g. the likelihood of obfuscating DML errors is higher if there is a trigger action involved).

My impression from your question is that these tables are mainly there because of some business logic, in which case I would handle the deletes outisde the database, in an ORM layer, for example.

Comment: Doesn't this leave the chance of "floating" records, i.e. you forget to delete them in the application layer and they stay in the DB forever as "orphaned" records?

Comment: yes, it certainly does: the question, in which context are those records regarded as being orphaned? Theoretically you could process *all* data relationships in the database, but in practice that can get messy.

Comment: "Orphaned" in the sense that the owner_id/owner_type (as in my example above) is deleted but e.g. settings are still in the tbl_settings. So you think that even a simple Trigger (if user deleted, delete settings) is not needed, I should just make sure that application is actually handing it property (deleting it where needed)?